# Is there a way to lock/unlock your screen with a USB in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04, usb, login, 18.10

I've seen programs like Pam and Cuttlefish, but both of them are so outdated that I'm unable to install them on my OS. I was wondering if there's a new program that will add a 2 factor authentication to my computer's login, does anyone know of one? Also, yes, I've seen some simple scripts to do it, but I'd like it to be secure, not just identifying if any USB with a specific name is plugged in.

Comment: Are you talking about pam_usb? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_usb  That one indeed seems to be unmaintained...

Comment: Yes, I was talking about pam_usb, and there used to be a program called Cuttlefish that was an all-around program, as far as I know, but I can't find anything for that either. I did find some pam files preinstalled on my system though, so once I get a U2F key, I'll look over them and see what I can find. Until then, however, I'd love to hear if anyone else has any other programs that I could try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I finally purchased a Feitian key and looked into the login more. It turns out that pam_usb works perfectly, and is preinstalled (mostly). You can go [here](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000011356-ubuntu-linux-login-guide-u2f) to learn how to do it yourself, but make sure you have their PPA enabled (which you can find [here](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000010964-enabling-the-yubico-ppa-on-ubuntu)). Lastly, make sure you have your udev set up correctly to accept the devices. If you're unsure how to do that, follow the steps [here](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006449-using-your-u2f-yubikey-with-linux) and then restart your computer.

Also, one last note: DON'T forget to test your key on sudo before you test it on your lock screen, because you'll end up getting completely locked out if you mess something up. Oh, and despite the fact that these are all Yubico articles, this works with any FIDO U2F capable key, it isn't just limited to Yubikeys or Feitian, but you can still follow all of Yubico's support pages to set everything up. Cheers!